# CSV file changes size when modified a little bit using panda data frames

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, size

I'm reading a CSV file and saving it as a panda data frame, changing it, and later saving it as another CSV file. The problem is the number of rows and columns and each element data size remains constant in this process, yet the size of the input and output CSV files differ significantly( input = 132 kB, output = 139 KB). I'm having a hard time understanding what's going on. I suspected encodings, and enforced them to be the same type both when reading and writing, but the issue remained.

What's more, if I open the output file manually and change a single element(say change only a 1 to 2 ), the size of the file goes back to 132 KB, which I expect. For your reference here is the code I'm using:

```
    user_df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
    answer = pd.DataFrame(columns=['question','worker','answer'])
```

After copying some fields of user data frame to answer data frame:

```
    answer.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Thanks a ton

Comment: Is anything about the data unexpected? Can you provide a minimum recreate-able example? At the moment I'm not sure the question provides enough information for an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer, the problem was the data types, even though one could not see them, one was float, while the other was integer. By forcing the output to be integer, the problem was solved. Thank you anyway.